# Why did this fog lamp turn on with either configuration of power/ground?

Tags: short-circuit, light

My friend and I were replacing a burnt out fog lamp on his car. When it was time to make the connection, I wanted to make sure which wire was power and ground, so we don’t cause a short to the new bulb. He insisted that the power/ground connection doesn’t matter as long as both are connected to either pin on the bulb’s socket. Since he had an extra bulb, we tested it in both configurations, and sure enough the light came on both times. The final connection was the one I thought to be most correct. But this challenged my understanding of diodes. Why did the light come on both times? Isn’t there a right and a wrong way of making the connection?

Comment: What if it was not a LED lamp? Or if it was a LED lamp, maybe it has a power supply that accepts supply voltage in both polarities like normal lamps? We don't know which lamp it is and how it works unless you tell this information.

Comment: Was the fog lamp an LED or incandescent?

Comment: TL;DR: Your understanding of diodes is fine... you're just not using one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Incandescent bulbs are bipolar.  That has nothing to do with their mental health, however, it means that they work the same with the current flowing in either direction.  LED bulbs, however, are unipolar, they work with current flowing in only one direction.

If you hook an incandescent bulb up, it doesn't matter which is + and which is - as either way will work.  LEDs must be hooked up properly or they won't work.

In some, mostly older, vehicles the lamp holder may be grounded and serve as the return path.  But in newer vehicles this is not done because it's easy to get a poor ground connection that way.  But the lamp itself still doesn't care.

Comment: Not everyone considers the mental health of their bulbs!

Comment: @Aaron maybe the one in their head ... lol

Comment: But if you would be connecting both lamps to the chassis and wouldn't know which is positive, which negative, there would be a potential problem

Comment: +1 for weirdness points.

Answer (score 5):

> Why did this fog lamp turn on with either configuration of power/ground?

1. Polarity would not matter with an incandescent-type fog lamp.

[image]

2. Polarity would also not matter with an LED-type fog lamp that has an inbuilt bridge rectifier.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Either you have a bulb with an element that requires no polarity (incandescent, halogen) or the  bulb has a device to make it ignore polarity.

A bridge rectifier or a full wave diode bridge of 4 specifically aligned diodes are typically used to polarize an AC signal. An ac signal will change polarity 60 times a second (example) and a bridge rectifier can smooth that out to make sure the same wire stays positive or negative.

You can also use a bridge rectifier on DC like in a car to make it not matter which way the power gets connected. It's just a very very stable AC signal.

[image: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Full-wave_rectifier.png#mw-jump-to-license]

Unlike just using one or two diodes that will block reverse polarity, with a full wave you get the benefit of always directing power where it needs to go.